# Fedora 37: cannot remove fwupdate-efi fwupdate-libs

Tags: fedora, dnf, delete

This box was originally Fedora 21 I think, and has been updated a few times like 21 -> 23 -> 25 -> ... -> 25 -> 37 (every odd version), and works fine.

However, I cannot clean these two old packages.

```
# dnf list extras
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:12 ago on Tue 31 Jan 2023 08:48:18 AM EET.
Extra Packages
fwupdate-efi.x86_64    11-4.fc29  @fedora
fwupdate-libs.x86_64   11-4.fc29  @fedora

# dnf erase fwupdate-efi fwupdate-libs
Error:
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: grub2-efi-x64, shim-x64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)

# dnf --skip-broken erase fwupdate-efi fwupdate-libs
Error:
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: grub2-efi-x64, shim-x64

# dnf --skip-broken --disableexcludes=all erase fwupdate-efi fwupdate-libs
Error:
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: grub2-efi-x64, shim-x64
```

This is an UEFI system (not legacy BIOS), but AFAIK secure boot is not used.

These (related/relevant) packages are installed

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i -e fwupd -e shim -e grub | sort
fwupd-1.8.10-2.fc37.x86_64
fwupdate-efi-11-4.fc29.x86_64
fwupdate-libs-11-4.fc29.x86_64
fwupd-efi-1.3-1.fc37.x86_64
fwupd-plugin-flashrom-1.8.10-2.fc37.x86_64
fwupd-plugin-modem-manager-1.8.10-2.fc37.x86_64
fwupd-plugin-uefi-capsule-data-1.8.10-2.fc37.x86_64
grub2-common-2.06-75.fc37.noarch
grub2-efi-x64-2.06-75.fc37.x86_64
grub2-pc-2.06-75.fc37.x86_64
grub2-pc-modules-2.06-75.fc37.noarch
grub2-tools-2.06-75.fc37.x86_64
grub2-tools-efi-2.06-75.fc37.x86_64
grub2-tools-extra-2.06-75.fc37.x86_64
grub2-tools-minimal-2.06-75.fc37.x86_64
grubby-8.40-66.fc37.x86_64
shim-x64-15.6-2.x86_64
```

How can I remove those two old packages (fwupdate-efi fwupdate-libs), and make sure my computer will continue booting OK?

Comment: Have you tried simply `sudo rpm -e fwupdate-libs fwupdate-efi` ?

Comment: Did man rpm, but not rpm -e yet. Have not needed rpm to install/remove packages, dnf (and yum before that) have served me well.

Comment: Did rpm -e fwupdate-libs fwupdate-efi and both packages uninstalled nicely. Thanks Artem.